# How to call standard javascript functions inside Swig template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

Specifically I want to call `{% if typeof(myvar) == "boolean" %}` or `{% set a = parseInt(myvar) %}`, but now it gives this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token !== at Object.Function () at
>   Object.precompile
>   (/home/aidan/Desktop/nodejs/turbo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:465:11)
>   at Object.compile
>   (/home/aidan/Desktop/nodejs/turbo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:560:16)
>   at Function.exports.swig.render
>   (/home/aidan/Desktop/nodejs/turbo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:246:56)
>   at
>   /home/aidan/Desktop/nodejs/turbo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:146:25
>   at
>   /home/aidan/Desktop/nodejs/turbo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:99:5
>   at fs.js:266:14 at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

Comment: Swig seems to parse your expression and can't handle `typeof` (which looks like a function, but isn't). The `set` statement should work though. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, I'm passing the template a value and want to check if it's an array, if so - check if the array contains the desired key: `if typeof myvar == "object" and myvar.indexOf(anothervar)`

Comment: Swig is not JavaScript. These functions are not supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a filter and then write a `set` statement with the filter applied to the variable. Finally you can use this variable in your `if` statement.

E.g.:

```
swig.setFilter('isObject', function(element) {
  return typeof element == "object";
});
```

Then:

```
{% set elementIsObject = myvar|isObject %}
{% if elementIsObject %} ... {% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.